# Getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Multithreaded UI program

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was working on an example from the book [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104) .Basically what the example does is count prime numbers in a specified range asynchronously and update the UI. When I run the code from the console it runs fine with the following output:
[image: Console Output]

However when I run the code from GUI I get the error the following error on Console(since the project is Console Application):

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: count
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(Int32 start, Int32 count)    at
>   Multithreading.TestUi.b__8(Int32 n) in
>   TestUI.cs:line 38

So, what did I miss? and How can I solve this?

Here is the code that is generating the error:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace Multithreading
{
    class TestUi:Window
    {

        private Button _button = new Button{Content = "Go"};
        private TextBlock _results = new TextBlock();

        public TestUi()
        {
            var panel = new StackPanel();
            panel.Children.Add(_button);
            panel.Children.Add(_results);
            Content = panel;
            _button.Click += (sender, args) => Go();
        }

        async void Go()
        {
            _button.IsEnabled = false; //disable the button while the calculation is proceeding.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int result = await GetPrimeCountAsyn(i*1000000, 1000000); //asynchronously calculate the prime numbers within the range
                _results.Text += String.Format("There are {0} primes between {1} and {2}{3}", result , (i * 100000), ((i+1) * 100000 - 1), Environment.NewLine);
            }
            _button.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        Task<int> GetPrimeCountAsyn(int start, int count)
        {
            int p = Enumerable.Range(start, count).Count(
                n => Enumerable.Range(2, (int) Math.Sqrt(n) - 1).All(i => n%i > 0));
            return Task.Run(() => p);

        }
        [STAThread]
       static void Main()
        {
            Application app = new Application();;
            app.Run(new TestUi());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1)`, `n` will equal `0` on your first run so you get `Enumerable.Range(2, -1)` which will throw a out of range exception.

This has nothing to do with running in a GUI, you made some kind of error going from console to GUI. Go put a breakpoint in your console version in `GetPrimeCountAsyn` either `start` is getting passed a value other than 0 or you don't have `Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n) - 1)`

Comment: Your are right! changing the call to GetPrimeCountAsyn(i*1000000 + 2, 1000000) solved it.